# PHP MYSQL - Highlight a database table row IF table1.id exists in table2

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, compare, record, highlight

I'm kinda of stuck here for a while maybe you guys can help me out? I want to highlight a table of database record, coming from one table, and check if the id out of this table also exists in the 2nd table. 
Let me be more specific:

```
Table 1: Projects (projectid pk)
Table 2: Reservations (projectid fk)
```

A simple sample code, to keep this simple:

```
while( $record=mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
    $projectid=$record['projectid'];
    echo "<tr>". $projectid ."</tr>; 
}
```

So this is working great, I get all table rows with each projectid which exists in my DB, but how to pass this `$projectid` variables to another query which checks if this exists in the other table, and if it exists, echo out something different? Here's my code which probably doesn't make much sense, but at least the logic is there... I hope?:

```
while( $record=mysql_fetch_array($result) ) 
{
    $projectid=$record['projectid'];
    $hasreservationquery = ("
                            SELECT * 
                            FROM reservelist rl
                                INNER JOIN project p on rl.projectid = p.projectid
                            WHERE rl.projectid = $projectid
                            ");
    $hasreservationqueryresult = mysql_query($hasreservationquery) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($hasreservationqueryresult > 1)
    {
    echo "<tr id='hasreservation'>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "". $projectid .""; 
}
```

Unfortunately this returns all tables highlighted, not just the one that really has a reservation in it. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ever appear to be checking the row count. you need to change your if statement:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($hasreservationqueryresult) > 0)
```

This will now check if 1 or more results are returned (change it to be > x if you want x + 1 results returned before you highlight).

Comment: This is it! Thank alot for the fast response. 

EDIT: Accept possible in 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query doesn't return the amount of affected rows.

I think something like

if($hasreservationqueryresult && mysql_num_rows($hasreservationqueryresult) > 0)

Except for that I'd definitely arrange your code a bit better and rethink your variable names :)

Comment: `hasreservationqueryresult` <- isn't very readable. When other programmers might stumble upon it one day they'll one to grab your head and smash it against the wall. I'd call id $hasResQ , or $hasReserveQ, or just $hasReservation. Just make it a bit tidier and more readable , same with the rest of your code - really hard to read.

Comment: PHP is a hard language to pick up naming conventions, because it doesn't follow one itself (open source and not enough restrictions). However it is always a good idea to pick a convention and follow it in code. Either underscores between words in a variable name, or CamelCase are common.